# Look for better code copy paste from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code and it worked well as I want. To look for some values and copy paste the result to another sheet (online for selected column)

I want to know the opinion from this community regarding my code

I just learned the VBA for 1 week. Hope you can share some good advice, thanks :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Analysis_ClientRating()   
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, rowppt As Long, colppt As Long
    Dim rowppt1 As Long, colppt1 As Long, rowppt2 As Long, colppt2 As Long
    Dim rowppt3 As Long, colppt3 As Long

    lastrow = ShNote.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    rowppt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colppt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rowppt1 = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colppt1 = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rowppt2 = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colppt2 = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rowppt3 = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colppt3 = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Call Entry_Point

    For i = 6 To lastrow
        Select Case ShNote.Cells(i, 5).Value
            Case Is = 20
            ShNote.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(rowppt + 6, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ShNote.Cells(i, 5).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(colppt + 6, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            rowppt = rowppt + 1
            colppt = colppt + 1

            Case Is >= 17
            ShNote.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(rowppt1 + 6, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ShNote.Cells(i, 5).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(colppt1 + 6, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            rowppt1 = rowppt1 + 1
            colppt1 = colppt1 + 1

            Case Is >= 15
            ShNote.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(rowppt2 + 6, 9).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ShNote.Cells(i, 5).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(colppt2 + 6, 10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            rowppt2 = rowppt2 + 1
            colppt2 = colppt2 + 1

            Case Is >= 11
            ShNote.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(rowppt3 + 6, 12).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ShNote.Cells(i, 5).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(colppt3 + 6, 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            rowppt3 = rowppt3 + 1
            colppt3 = colppt3 + 1
        End Select
    Next i

    Call Exit_Point
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asked for an opinion (which is off-topic) and the question would be better asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hello, I am new on community. Thanks for your reply, I will put my code on the link that you share.

Comment: Before it gets closed, i can suggest a quick shortcut to your copy/paste... `ShPPT.Cells(colppt + 6, 3).value = ShNote.Cells(i, 3).value` can replace `ShNote.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(rowppt + 6, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` . Also you seem to be allocating the same value (row count) to a number of variables..., you could do that once (i.e. var1 = row number), then just make your var2 = var1, var3 = var1, etc, etc. I`m not even trying to understand why so many variables that represent the same value, you might have your reasons... though from code is not very apparent.